# How to add constrain to pick stories (or tasks) in a solution from large list which sum up to given Team capacity using Cplex Python?

Tags: python, optimization, cplex, constraint-programming, docplex

I am using the IBM cplex Python API and working on the problem to find stories from list of thousand stories which sum up to the given Team Capacity for different sprints (2 weeks of sprint here). Each story has assigned Story points &belongs to particular Team. There are some constrains like end_before_start (some stories should implement before some other stories) and workUsage = given Team capacity (need to select stories which exactly sum to given Capacity).

But problem here is if I make all the interval variables (for stories) as optional and leave the model decide which stories to pick then it's not giving solution for any story. And When I make all stories as not optional then Model fails as well as I believe it's because model thinks all stories are mandatory and need to fit all of them. So please let me know any idea or approach how to do it?
This is what I have tried so far.

```
 # Create dictionary of interval variables (for Stories)
 dictIntrvalVars = {}
 for idx, row in dfAnalyzerOrg.iterrows():
    isOptional = row['Stories'] not in dfAnalyzer['Stories'].values
    dictIntrvalVars[row['Stories']] = mdl0.interval_var(name = row['Stories'], size = 
 int(row['Story Points']), optional=isOptional)

 # Constrain capacity of resources

 #Making team wise dictionary list of interval vars
 dictTeamWise = {team:[] for team in dfTeamCapacity['Team'].values}
 print(dictTeamWise)
 for itm in dictIntrvalVars.items():
    dictTeamWise[dfAnalyzerOrg.loc[dfAnalyzerOrg['Stories']==itm[0], 'Team'].iloc[0]].append(itm)

 NB_SPRINTS = 2
 SPRINT_INTERVAL = 20
 for t, lstTeam in dictTeamWise.items():
    sCapacity = 0
    sCapacity = sum(step_at(SPRINT_INTERVAL * s, dfTeamCapacity.loc[dfTeamCapacity['Team'] == t, 
 s+1].iloc[0]) for s in range(NB_SPRINTS))
    
    sCapacity -= sum(step_at_start(tpl[1], int(dfAnalyzerOrg.loc[dfAnalyzerOrg['Stories']==tpl[0], 'Story Points'].iloc[0])) 
                     for tpl in lstTeam)
    mdl0.add(sCapacity.equals(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would model this as a variant of a standard assignment problem with binary variables:

```
  i : tasks
  j : teams

  max sum((i,j), points[i,j]*x[i,j])
      sum(i, x[i,j]*usage[i]) <= capacity[j]   ∀j
      sum(j, x[i,j]) <= 1                      ∀i  (in case a task can only be done by one single team)
      x[i,j] ∈ {0,1}
```

(I am inventing here things, as I don't understand your code). Staying much closer to the math will help make things more understandable readable and easier to document. In addition, this can now easily be transcribed into any language and modeling tool.

Adding precedence constraints is easy:

```
 x[i2,j] <= x[i1,j]    ∀j
```

means i2 can only be used when i1 is also chosen.

More information on the assignment problem can be found in almost any book on linear optimization.